# material.angular.io responsive titlebar /toolbar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-design

How did the material.angular.io achieved the effect where buttons from top toolbar (Component, CDK, Guide) comes to the next row as tabbar when you hit the lower breakpoint?

Comment: For a start, consider taking a look at Chrome DevTools as to what Mitch stated in his answer, as well as taking a look at the source code available on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use two separate `<nav>` elements and set `display: none` on the one with class `.docs-navbar-show-small` unless it is the smaller break point. They do the opposite for the top ones, displaying when the view is larger and hiding when it is smaller. So it ends up looking something like this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="docs-navbar-header">
  <!--nav options here-->
</nav>
<nav class="docs-navbar-show-small">
  <!--same nav options here-->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint) {
  .docs-navbar-header {
    display: hidden;
  }
  .docs-navbar-show-small {
    display: flex;
    ...
  }
}
@meda screen and (min-width: $breakpoint) {
  .docs-navbar-header {
    display: flex;
    ...
  }
  .docs-navbar-show-small {
    display: hidden
  }
}
```

From devtools:

[image]

Comment: So, they are using <app-navbar class="mat-elevation-z6"></app-navbar> but if you look at the list of components (https://material.angular.io/components/categories) , there is no documentation for navbar

Is this something the they removed from Material2

Comment: No, this is an angular component they have built within their own project. It is probably something called `NavbarComponent`. You can put a class of `mat-elevation-z6` or whatever number you want on any element. It just adds the box-shadow.